# Return just the value of a query instead of a key pair of "column":"value" inside a function

Tags: laravel

I have this function in my user model:

```
public function adminlte_image()
{
   return Employee::where('user_id',$this->id)->get('image');
}
```

Which returns:

```
[
   {"image":"Base64 String"}
]
```

But instead what I want is just the value of that column being returned instead of a json, since that function is being called in a img src:

```
<img src="Base64 String" class="user-image img-circle elevation-2" alt="Mathias Oliveira">
```

Here is what it looks like with the present code:

```
<img src="[{"image":"Base64 String"}]" class="user-image img-circle elevation-2" alt="Mathias Oliveira">
```

I cannot edit the html or how the function is called, only the function itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```php
public function adminlte_image()
{
   return Employee::where('user_id',$this->id)->firstOrFail()->image;
}
```

`firstOrFail` will ensure that when there's no record with user_id = $this->id then it will not throw an error of accessing image property on null, rather it will throw a ModelNotFound exception when no model record is found for the given user_id = $this->id

> While that worked, is there any way to return null if there is no record instead of a ModelNotFound exception?

```php
public function adminlte_image()
{
    $emp = Employee::where('user_id',$this->id)->first();

    return $emp ? $emp->image : null;

    //OR using optional helper

    return optional(Employee::where('user_id', $this->id)->first())->image;
}
```

Laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional

Comment: While that worked, is there any way to return null if there is no record instead of a ModelNotFound exception?